# Optimizing Python Algorithm for a particular Use Case using Pre-Computing

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, hash, hashmap

I am trying to solve a specific variant of the problem mentioned here:

Given a string s and a string t, check if s is subsequence of t.

I wrote an algorithm that works fine for the above question:

```
def isSubsequence(s, t):
        """
        :type s: str
        :type t: str
        :rtype: bool
        """
        i = 0

        for x in t:
            if i<len(s) and x==s[i]:
                i = i + 1

        return i==len(s)
```

Now there is a particular use case:

If there are lots of incoming S, say S1, S2, ... , Sk where k >= 1 Billion, and you want to check one by one to see if T has its subsequence.

There is a hint:

```
/**
 * If we check each sk in this way, then it would be O(kn) time where k is the number of s and t is the length of t. 
 * This is inefficient. 
 * Since there is a lot of s, it would be reasonable to preprocess t to generate something that is easy to search for if a character of s is in t. 
 * Sounds like a HashMap, which is super suitable for search for existing stuff. 
 */
```

But the logic seems like inverting the logic of the algorithm above algorithm, if s is traversed and the character is searched in t using hashmap, it will not be always correct as a hashmap of t will have only 1 index for that character and there is no guarantee that the order will be preserved.

So, I am stuck at how to optimize the algorithm for the above use case?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are the expected sizes of `t` and `s`?

Comment: t could be very large, s has to be less than t for subsequence property to be valid.

Answer (score 2):

For each `i` less than `len(t)`, and each character `c` that occurs in `t`, make a mapping from `(i,c)->j`, where `j` is the first index >= `i` that at which `c` occurs.

Then you can iterate through each Sk, using the map to find the next occurrence of each required character, if it exists.

This is essentially making a deterministic finite automaton that matches subsequences of `t` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton).

Answer (score 1):

You can preprocess `t` to create a list of all possible subsequences (keep in mind that `t` will have `2^len(t)-1` subsequences). You can turn this into a hashtable and then iterate over your list of `s`, checking for each `s` in the table. the advantage is you don't have to iterate over `t` for each `s`.

By the way, if you get stuck on preprocessing `t` for a list of all subsequences, you should look into `powerset` and its implementation in python.